# Sublime text 2 prints wrong comment block on shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

For some time now, when i hit cmd-/ (mac) in .php files it prints the comments for html,
and not for php.

so it does  instead of //

the format is set to PHP, and it shows 'php' on the bottom right of the editor,
also all the syntax highlighting is fine.

any idea?

thanks :)
T

Answer (score 0):

Sublime is decent, I prefer notepad++ and brackets for development. For your issue, uninstall than install Sublime in default, see if it works. If it does work, and you have custom plugins for it, add one at a time and test. To see what is causing the problem. If nothing is causing the problem and you have everything set to how you had it prior. I am guessing that some form of data corruption occured or the shortcut for a comment in php is mixed up with the comment in html. The text editor shouldn't be treating a completely different language as another. I hope this helped.

Comment: You don't need to uninstall.  Just rename your [data](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory) folder and open Sublime.  It will recreate this folder with the defaults.  But, it's probably a package you installed.

Answer (score 0):

What commenting is done is based on the scoping rules. I'm not a PHP programmer so I might get some of the details wrong, but you should get the general idea. If I understand correctly, PHP files consist of a mix of HTML elements and PHP code blocks. ST allows for languages to be "embedded" within another file type (in this case, embedding HTML in the PHP syntax). If the cursor is in an html region, it will use HTML commenting. If it is a PHP region, it will use PHP commenting. I know there are some issues with edge cases, but try moving the cursor into the actual PHP code block, then using the comment command. You could probably find a modified language file that will just treat everything as PHP if you want.

To check the scopes begin applied, you can use the [ScopeHunter](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter) plugin. Alternatively, you can use the `ctrl+alt+shift+p` in windows and linux or `cmd+alt+p` in osx to display the scope in the status bar.

I hope that helps clarify how commenting works. How you choose to actually "solve" this is up to you though, as it's more of a personal preference thing.

Comment: hi skuroda. thanks, yeah the scope it says is 'text.html.basic source.php.embedded.block.html' however, there is no html in that file, also no embedded html.. i'll go check if some other plugin overrode this.

Comment: It looks like the html scopes are applied across the whole document by default. But when I am in a block surrounded by `<?php ?>` it uses PHP style comments. Can you post a snippet (and the cursor position)? I'm curious as to why I'm getting the correct commenting style, and you are not.